# How can I solve $2y^{\prime\prime}=\exp(y)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried taking $z = \exp(y)$ and then after calculations I got the follow equation:
$$
z^{\prime\prime}-(z^\prime)^2=z^3.
$$
How do I solve it from here?

Comment: Do you know the method of separation of variables?

Comment: That seems a lot tougher to solve. Instead why not multiply both sides of the original equation by $y'$ and integrate?

Comment: With $z=e^y$ you get $z''=z(y''+y'^2)=z(z/2+y'^2)$ which does not reduce further. But you could take the derivative to get $2y'''=e^yy'=2y''y'$, so with $y'=z$ this becomes $z''=zz'$.

Answer (score 3):

1)-multiply both sides with $y'$ 
2)-integrate both sides 
You get: 
$y'^2=\exp(y)+c$ 
If you have initial conditions you can get the C 
3) YOU GET :
$y'=\pm \sqrt{\exp(y)+c}$
4)separable DE 
You can do it easily now !

Comment: You can get $\pm$ by using \pm, and $\sqrt x, \exp$, etc by using \sqrt x, \exp, etc